# Can't append HTML code into one div by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one div id=userinfo

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id=userinfo></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And now I want to append something into this div, depending on the localStorage.

```
if (localStorage==0){$("#userinfo").append("<p>Test</p>");} else {$("#userinfo").append("<p>Hello</p>");}
```

But it failed, no matter I input this script into separate JS file or add them into the head of the html file.
I tried exclude this with Google chrome developer tool's console, it works as expected.

I've tried another way round change the script into:

```
if (localStorage==0){alert("Test");} else {alert("Hello");}
```

And add this into JS file, it works!

So, now I'm stacked why my jQuery code not work?

Comment: I tried it and it works. Can you reproduce the error on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Did you tried your code placing inside $(document).ready(function() {});?

Comment: Hi Asif Mulla, thanks for your hint. It works after I placing them inside $(document).ready(function(){});  if you want, you can post this as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The jquery append function takes an object as parameter and not a string html.
So this should solve your problem, `$("#userinfo").append($('<p>Test</p>'))`

Comment: not really. It can accept plain text or html as well. [link](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

You might have conflicts with other javascript libraries. Try to check out http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery  we can do like this below

`$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( "#userinfo" );`