# PHP/AJAX: Can't seem to be able to display ajax result into DIV, but works in ALERT()

Tags: php, html, jquery, xmlhttprequest, jquery-append

I'm currently learning PHP through a real website project and want to use Ajax calls to change sections of the website.

> **CODE SAMPLE**

myproject.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inventory").click(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            url: "sectionhandler.php?section='inventory'",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html"
        });
        $.ajax().done(function(html) { 
            alert(html); // This works!
            $("#section").html(html); // This doesn't work.
            $("#section").append(html); // This neither.
        });
    });
});
```

inventory.html

```
<table><tr><td>Hello world with AJAX!</td></tr></table>
```

sectionhandler.php

```
<?php echo file_get_contents( 'inventory.html' ); ?>
```

menu.html

```
<a id="inventory" href="">Inventory</a>
```

index.php

```
<div id="menu" class="content"><?php echo file_get_contents( 'menu.html' ); ?></div>
<div id="section" class="content"></div>
```

> **RELATED ARTICLES FOUND AND READ AND TRIED**

1. [XMLHttpRequest won't work in IE 7/8 but works in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418403/xmlhttprequest-wont-work-in-ie-7-8-but-works-in-other-browsers)
2. [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
3. [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)
4. [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
5. [jquery .html() vs .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append)
6. [Can't append HTML code into one div by using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282655/cant-append-html-code-into-one-div-by-using-jquery)
7. [Add Html to Div with effect jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606029/add-html-to-div-with-effect-jquery)
8. [Use append() to add text/html to an element with jQuery](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-append-add-text-to-element/)

And there are many many more...

> **RESULT**

When I click on the Inventory link contained within `menu.html` and displayed through `index.php`, the jQuery code executes just fine. I get the result from the server while displaying the right content from `inventory.html` in the `alert()`.

However, when I come to either set the `innerHTML` to the `<div id="section" class="content"></div>`, I can't seem to be able to get the expected result. The background of the page seems to flash, though not supposed to as per Ajax definition, and the content of my `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` never get displayed.

The closer I got to make it work was when I was double-clicking on the `Inventory` link, so that after the first "flash" from the page background, it showed the content of my section.

I have tried multiple ways using classic Javascript with an `onclick` element on my `<a>` tag, I have tried with `document.getElementById("section")`, though getting the right element, I was not able to show my content on the page.

Any thoughts are welcome!

Thanks in advance ! =)

Comment: Here is what is alerted: http://prntscr.com/ykc2n

Comment: How can it work when I write `<?php echo file_get_contents( 'inventory.html' ); ?>` directly into the div:#section within the `index.php` file, and not work when going through ajax? I'm missing something, I'm confused. =)

Comment: can you try `$("#section").load("sectionhandler.php?section=inventory");` instead of the ajax and see if that works?

Comment: @Onimusha: This would be even better/simpler approach. I shall try this immediately! =)

Comment: @Onimusha: This works also flawlessly, and is ridiculously simple! I'm lovin' it! lol All these hours passed to investigate this and that solution with as many variances, great! I'll remember this for sure! =) If you wish, you may write your approach as an answer so that I can upvote and help for rep points. =)

Comment: Glad it helped :) posted as answer as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all chance, you need to prevent browser default behavior:

```
$("#inventory").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    ...

});
```

Notice the `event` parameter added to the click handler.

By the way, you HTML response is invalid - a `<table>` should contain a `<tbody>` element wrapping any `<tr>`s.

Comment: +1&Accepted: event.preventDefault() is the solution! =) I have already read and tried this through a `return false` which also prevents the default behaviour, and I have never thought about it while trying this, since it is mentioned nowhere that one must prevent the default behaviour of the browser. THANKS! This solves my problem! =)

Answer (score 1):

As requested. A more simple solution

```
$("#section").load("sectionhandler.php?section=inventory");
```

[jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: +1 This helped me achieve what I needed. Thanks for your response! =)